# php edits specific apache config

Tags: php, apache, config

I would like to write a php function which would parse a specific apache conf file and would add to server alias new domains, than on user event would restart my apache server. Is it possible to do this I have been taking a look on the following pear library http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.configuration.config.avail-container.apache.php but I can not decide if would do the job or not.

Comment: Yes, good research. That would do the job.

Comment: thanks for your feedback! Is there something what needs special attention when I implement my method?